# Load local XML document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to load and explore a local XML file in one of my webpages. However using the code below:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlpath = "http://www.xxxx.co.uk/files/myxml.xml";                
xmlDoc.Load(xmlpath);
```

I get the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Any ideas?

Comment: path `"http://www.xxxx.co.uk/....`" doesn't seems to be local

Comment: Assuming that the own webserver can resolve its own public server name and also access its own URL directly via HTTP(S) is sometimes/often a wrong assumption. Configuring a proxy _might_ help.

Comment: the xxx.co.uk is my web page so for an image i would use "\image\img.jpg" i tried "\files\myxml.xml" but that doe snot work.

Comment: @UweKeim - Sorry not sure what you mean by proxy. Save the xml file on a different page?

Comment: combine `env.WebRootPath` from `IHostingEnvironment env`  with your path

Comment: From webpage use file://c:/files/myxml.xml or make folder shared so it can be accessed from network.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution using : Server.MapPath("~/files/myxml.xml");
Thanks for your help.